# Haversine's formula implementation with SQLAlchemy and performance

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, haversine

Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy ORM to implement the Haversine's formula instead of using a raw SQL query with it?

My SQL implementation at the moment is:

```
SELECT
    places.*,
    6373.0 * (2 * atan2(sqrt(temp), sqrt(1 - temp))) as distance
FROM (
    SELECT 
        places.*,
        power(sin(d_lat / 2), 2) + cos(RADIANS(places.latitude)) * cos(RADIANS(<some_user_latitude>)) * power(sin(d_long / 2), 2) as temp
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            places.*, 
            RADIANS(<some_user_latitude>) - RADIANS(places.latitude) as d_lat, 
            RADIANS(<some_user_longitude>) - RADIANS(places.longitude) as d_long 
        FROM
            public.places as places
        ) as places
) as places
```

Although this implementation works just fine, I wanted to know:

1. Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy `.query()` to create the same results without using any raw SQL in it?
2. Is it possible to map the results to a custom model (for eg Place)?
3. Is there any improvements in terms of performance I can do to my raw SQL or sqlalchemy, or is this implementation okay?